# Will StackExchange Area51 Drones Community clear clutter in Aviation?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Does the drone community cause significant clutter in Aviation community?

If so, will a specific Drones Community benefit Aviation by clearing said clutter?

Answer (score 7):

You have two different question there, I'll try to address them separately.

> Does the drone community cause significant clutter in Aviation community?

Depends on the meaning of clutter. Speaking as a mod, I would say no, I don't see major clutter right now. Speaking as a user, I feel the various posts about quadrocopters a bit borderline, if not off-topic for this community, particularly when not asking about our core topics: regulations, aerodynamics, flight dynamics, and so on.

> Will a specific Drones Community benefit Aviation by clearing said clutter?

The main point of a new SE site is to serve a community previously unserved by the existing SE communities, not to split a community in two. If there is a drone community that feels they cannot ask questions here because they are off-topic, then yes, a Drone.SE would definitely benefit them, but it is not on us to say so or otherwise.

Comment: At least one community has been split in the past - Network Engineering was spun off of Server Fault. Plus there can be overlap. There are at least three stacks where questions on Ubuntu would usually be on-topic. At the same time, Mathematics gets a very large number of questions and could be split to manage them more easily, but it's not practical to do so because there's no reasonable line or lines along which to divide up the topics on Mathematics. Anyway, just wanted to point out that a split is a thing, but has only happened once that I know of.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it creates clutter, but it does seem to create useful and relevant questions and answers. The only "clutter" that comes to mind is the time someone with a toy helicopter (the tiny ones you get from toy shops) couldn't understand why his experience isn't transferable to flying a real helicopter, and that was at least a year ago.

Comment: interesting view.  tks.