# What is the site policy on drone questions?

Tags: discussion, faq, off-topic, questions, on-topic

What is the site policy on questions about Drones and Unmanned Aerial Vehicles (UAVs)?

Answer (score 3):

We have had two previous consultations on the subject of Drones/UAVs here at Aviation StackExchange, and have roughly come to the same conclusion in both.

Further reading:

- [How should we handle the new drones.SE site?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4084/how-should-we-handle-the-new-drones-se-site)
- [Do we have a clear policy on drone questions?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/do-we-have-a-clear-policy-on-drone-questions)

### In short

1. Uses should of course feel free to participate in [drones.se](https://drones.stackexchange.com/) if it is a subject which interests them - Please refer to their [on-topic](https://drones.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page before asking questions there.
2. Aviation.SE users would like to focus their attention on anything to do with aviation covered by the [on topic guidelines](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) with a focus on "full scale" aviation. That does not necessarily mean that all questions about smaller scale aviation will automatically be off-topic here.
3. Questions which relate *only* to drones/UAVs asked here should be migrated to Drones StackExchange.

---

### In detail

A closer look at our on topic subjects with an eye to Drones/UAVs

##### Flying technique

- If the question is very specific to the technique of flying small RC/unmanned aircraft and this does not translate to larger scale aircraft it should be better suited to Drones.se
- If it is a general question about flying technique unaffected by the scale of the aircraft it can be asked on Aviation.se.

##### Air Traffic Control or Aviation regulations

- The only questions I think would make sense about Drones in this area would be how the regulations may affect users of Drones in and around controlled airspace and these no doubt make more sense on Aviation.se

##### Aerodynamics

- This is probably the most contentious one. Here at Aviation.se we have a number of experts on aerodynamics and often this expertise can be translated perfectly well to small-scale aviation. Therefore, feel free to ask these questions on either Drones.se or Aviation.se as you see fit. The community here will answer if they are able to.
- If the question is very specific to the aerodynamics of small scale drones or RC aircraft, and is not applicable to larger scale then it is better suited to Drones.se

##### Aviation Safety

- Questions on aviation safety relating to Drones should be specific to Drones and therefore should be asked on Drones.se
- If the question is actually about the safety of full-scale aircraft around Drone users, then it may well be better suited to Aviation.se

##### Aircraft Design and Manufacture

- Any questions about building Drones or RC aircraft belong on Drones.se as do anything to do with the electronics/control setup of such aircraft.
- For questions to do with aerodynamic design see the above points on Aerodynamics.