# Please enable a migration path to Drones Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

We have an increasing number of drone questions show up on Aviation, some of which might be suitable for migration to [Drones Stack Exchange](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com).

We have [previously](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4084/how-should-we-handle-the-new-drones-se-site) [discussed](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/do-we-have-a-clear-policy-on-drone-questions) how we would like to handle drone questions on stack exchange, as well as [co-ordinating with the folks over at Drones.se](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223/how-would-you-like-aviation-stackexchange-to-deal-with-drone-uav-questions) regarding what questions may be suitable to be migrated there. We've written an [FAQ](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4390/what-is-the-site-policy-on-drone-questions) on the subject with the outcome of these discussions.

CMs, please set us up a migration path so the community can vote on these migrations and not have it a mod-only tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We looked into this and determined that this migration would be valuable. We have the pathway active now for you to use.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciated